# exclude weekends from datetime

Tags: vb.net

I need to exclude weekends from this line.

```
 If Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells(4).Text).ToString < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3) Then
                            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("red")
```

I hope there is an easy way to do this!

Comment: How can it be asp-classic *and* C#? And in what possible way is that code C#?

Comment: woops sorry bout that its actually vb. using visual studio with a table and have attached that bit of code to a rowdatabound event

Comment: So there's *still* no reason to have the C# tag, right?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code

```
DateDiff(DateInterval.Weekday,Date2, Date1)
```

--Hiren V

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something similar once.

The trick is to take the strings from your rows, convert them to a DateTime like you have it, then check the DayOfWeek property of the DateTime object.

The DayOfWeek property can be used as such:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime();
label1.text = date.DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

With that, just check if the value is equal to a string of "Saturday" or "Sunday".

That should help you filter off your weekends.

Comment: Why would you convert the DayOfWeek value to a string and then compare string values, rather than comparing the property directly with the enum value?

Comment: sorry i actually need to -3 days (weekdays) from todays date not including the weeknds.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't do it the way Jon said. Enumerated is much faster.